# How to point consul-cli to HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: consul

How to point consul cli to HTTPS url?

I tried the below ...

```sh
export CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR=127.0.0.1:8501
consul members                        
Error retrieving members: Unexpected response code: 400 (Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah..

```sh
export CONSUL_HTTP_SSL=true
consul members             
Node            Address             Status  Type    Build   Protocol  DC   Segment
myhostname      192.168.2.198:8301  alive   server  1.10.4  2         dc1  <all>
```